# "Start > Search" does not work on Windows 7 

Tags: windows-7, search

I don't know why but the start->search line in my computer - does not work!

It shows me something that says Programs as result and does not search!

I used to just type something like CMD and it will open cmd.

Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following page for troubleshooting your symptoms: [Windows 7 Start search bar not working](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-start-search-bar-not-working-windows/532627cc-47d6-4399-bcd8-acc9c5e48cea)

Comment: so the only option is to create new user? I prefer not..

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: restart the *explorer.exe* process - 
[Windows 7 Start Menu search not working](https://superuser.com/questions/277405/windows-7-start-menu-search-not-working)

I have found various suggestions for solutions, including

- [a registry edit](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-start-search-bar-not-working-windows/532627cc-47d6-4399-bcd8-acc9c5e48cea)
- [deleting c:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\1033\StructuredQuerySchema.bin](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/4d853a94-328f-4c50-8719-838834d51fde%29)
- [index rebuilding](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/11189-search-box-start-menu-does-not-work.html)
- the above solution

I was reluctant to try those rather complex solutions, then I noticed that beside the start search not working, also the calendar wouldn't pop up. Remembering the useful trick from WinXP, I restarted the *explorer.exe* process and presto.